# Get one day prior date using jodastime library

Tags: java, jodatime

I need to figure out a way to get one day prior date not including weekends.

Such as: Suppose its July 1, 2013 and i want to get one day prior date so it should return June 28, 2013 not June 30, 2013.

I have used Calendar library a lot but after researching while it looks like JodaTime library is way to go.

Comment: How come 1 day prior takes you 3 days back?

Comment: @RohitJain: Not including weekends...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
static LocalDate oneDayBackExcludingWeekends(LocalDate date) {
    do {
        date = date.minusDays(1);
    } while (date.getDayOfWeek() == DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY ||
             date.getDayOfWeek() == DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY); 
    return date;
}
```

You could be more efficient, mind you:

```
static LocalDate oneDayBackExcludingWeekends(LocalDate date) {
    switch (date.getDayOfWeek()) {
        case DateTimeConstants.MONDAY:
            return date.minusDays(3);
        case DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY:
            return date.minusDays(2);
        default:
            return date.minusDays(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really appreciated but what if the date falls under holidays. Such as July 4th(Independence Day) would that still work?

Comment: @user2501165: No, but then that's not what you asked for. You'd need to have a list of holidays, bearing in mind that different countries will have different holidays...

Comment: oh ok i got it now. Thanks!